# Create relative entropy matrix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, entropy

I have a dataframe of values, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

in which every row is a vector of probabilities. I want to compute something like the correlation matrix of `df.corr()` , but instead of correlation, I want to compute the [relative entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html).

What is the best way to do this, as I can't find a way to get inside the `.corr()` method and simply change the function it uses?

Comment: Is the relative entropy of `entropy(arr, arr)` expected to be 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use [`.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import entropy

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

res = df.corr(method=entropy)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          a         b         c
a  1.000000  0.160246  0.270608
b  0.160246  1.000000  0.167465
c  0.270608  0.167465  1.000000
```

From the documentation:

> callable:
> **callable with input two 1d ndarrays and returning a float.**
> Note that the returned matrix from corr will have 1 along the
> diagonals and will be symmetric regardless of the callable’s behavior.

Comment: Oh, I did not see the callable part in the .corr flag. Thanks :)